# Efficient binary messages (Avro?) through PubSub?

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

It looks like Google PubSub in its current form is very JSON-centric.

Let's say I want to publish data that can be easily ingested by a hadoop cluster. My natural choice would be to serialize the data as Avro on the publisher side, then consume it with ease from Hadoop.

What are the options/best practices for doing this with PubSub? I guess I can pack Avro in the "data" field in a JSON structure but that feels a bit awkward. Is there a binary version of PubSub coming up? The internets talk a bit about gRPC support, will that help me?

Answer (score 1):

We have [just announced gRPC support for Google Cloud Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/03/announcing-grpc-alpha-for-google-cloud-pubsub), which supports binary encoding and a much more efficient protocol. The feature is [documented here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/grpc-overview).